# javascript function in while loop

Tags: php, javascript, while-loop

I have some data from the database posted with a while loop:

```
$dati = $link->query($sql);
    print '<table>';

        while ($dato = $dati->fetch_object()) {

            print '<tr>';
            print '<td id="cellaId">';
            $Id = $dato->Id;
            print $Id;
            print '</td>';

            print '<td>';
            print $dato->Data;
            print '</td>';

            ...some other stuff...

            print '<td>';
            print '<input type = "checkbox" name = "visto" id = "visto" onclick = "refreshData()">';
            print '</td>';

            print '<td>';
            print '<input type = "checkbox" name = "elaborato" id = "elaborato" onclick = "refreshData()">';
            print '</td>';

            print '</tr>';
        }
        print '</table>';
        $dati->close();
```

Now those two "checkbox" call a function:

```
function refreshData() {

var vistovalue = document.getElementById("visto").checked ? '1' : '0'
var elaboratovalue = document.getElementById("elaborato").checked ? '1' : '0'
var idvalue = document.getElementById("cellaId").innerHTML

alert(idvalue);

[and then I do an ajax]
}
```

The problem is that the idvalue I get is always the first coming out from the while loop and not that on the same line where I click the checkbox.

How can I get the right value??

Thank you!

Comment: You absolutely **cannot** have multiple elements with the same `id`. Each element (if requiring an `id`) should be given a unique one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one unique ID on a html page.

What you can do, is add a counter or `$dato->Id` to the ID so that it is unique and you can identify it. You could then call your function with that ID as a parameter.

Example:

```
print '<input type="checkbox" name="visto[' . $dato->Id . ']"
        id="visto' . $dato->Id . '" onclick="refreshData(' . $dato->Id . ')">';
```

and:

```
function refreshData(Id) {
  var elID = 'visto' + Id;
  // etc.
```

You have the same problem with your `name` attributes, so you could do something similar there like in my example (I'm using an array so that you will get an array when the form is posted).

Comment: perfect! Thank you!! The name is not important, I don't need it, only the ID to update the database when the checkbox is selected!

Comment: yeah, I tried to do that but I have to wait! I'll do that later ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Jut out of a quick look here...
It's better to keep your IDs unique. Make a counter in your while loop, and set `id="cellaId"+counter`

Then you can pass `onClick="refreshData("+count+")"`

Let me know if it works.